# Access HttpServletRequest in custom javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule

Tags: java, security, weblogic

We have a custom `javax.security.auth.spi.LoginModule` used for web services as well as some web applications on a Weblogic 11g.

The goal is to record information regarding logins when going through the `LoginModule`, especially failed logins. Part of the desired information is the IP address that the authentication request came from. The problem I'm finding is I'm not sure how to get this information into the `LoginModule`.

Currently the `LoginModule` just verifies that the specified username and password match the values stored in a JDBC database. If the authentication fails it increments a counter to track the number of failed logins for that user, if they exist as a valid user. The username and password are passed in, if I understand it correctly, via the `CallbackHandler` that is specified during the `initialize` method. I'm not clear how these values get into the `CallbackHandler` at first and how to specify other dynamic content such as the request's originating IP address. Through debugging I've found that the `CallbackHandler` does indeed have the request in the following chain: `handler.ch.delegate.contextHandler.requestElement` but I do not see how to get access to any of that from the `CallbackHandler` interface.

I researched some on AuditProviders and the like, finding [one example that logged the HTTP method](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81b/dvspisec/aud.html#1168724), so I would imagine that getting additional information from the HTTP Request would be possible, I've just not yet discovered it. However I will have to modify our custom Security Provider to create the `AuditEvent`s to be audited. Part of that would be providing the Request, which gets us back to the initial problem of accessing the `HttpServletRequest` from within a `LoginModule`.

I tried implementing a `ServletAuthenticationFilter` as part of our Security Provider, but it seems that is call BEFORE authentication, which does not help us in capturing failed login attempts.

I'm relatively new to developing/modifying the security providers so basic examples/explanations are best.

Thanks!

Comment: How your custom LoginModul work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We capture the callback handler during `LoginModule.initialize(Subject subject, CallbackHandler callbackHandler, Map sharedState, Map options)` and store it as an attribute so that during the `LoginModule.login()` call we can pass in our callbacks and have the provided handler process it, getting us the data we want.

We used a `weblogic.security.auth.callback.ContextHandlerCallback` and have the `javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler`, specified during initialize, process this callback object via the `javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler.handle(Callback[])` method. Then you can gain access to the request with the following code:

```
ContextHandler handler = contextHandlerCallback.getContextHandler();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)handler.getValue("com.bea.contextelement.servlet.HttpServletRequest");
```